# how to generate an event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I created a subclass from UIView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MeeSelectDropDownView : UIView {
    UILabel *mainText;
    UIImage *bgImg;
    UIImageView *bgView;
    UIImageView *originView;
    NSMutableArray *labelArray;
    int selectedItem;
    BOOL inSelectTag;
    float _defaultHeight;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain)  UIImage *bgImg;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  UIImageView *bgView;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  NSMutableArray *labelArray;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  UIImageView *originView;
@property (nonatomic , retain)  UILabel *mainText;
@property (nonatomic , readonly)  int selectedItem;


- (void) setViewHeight:(float)aheight;
-(void) showDropList;
-(void) hiddenDropList;
-(void) setStringByArray:(NSArray*)array;

-(void)hiddenLabels
{
    for(UILabel *aLabel in labelArray){
        [aLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }   
}
```

Is it possible to generate an Event from function 'hiddenLabels' to inform and do somethings

Thanks

interdev

Comment: what is your purpose...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally unclear what you are trying to do.

Suggestion: you can consider either posting an `NSNotification`, or registering observers using KVO (Key Value Observing).